# It is not possible to read source code .java file

Tags: java, android, windows, android-studio, system

When I was working on Android Studio with source codes,my comp suddenly shutted down.Then I again opened my comp ,and I could not open NoteMainFragment.java file

[image on Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1z1pQ.jpg)

[image from NotePad++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeXgx.jpg)

Comment: May be your file got corrupted due to sudden shut down!

Comment: Looks corrupted. You had it in version control, right?

Comment: what is your "comp" ?

Comment: My Comp is HP.How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Maybe you are lucky and you have a `NoteMainFragment.class` somewhere, that you can decompile.

Comment: unfortunately,I don't have .class file , I have .apk file ,but I could not get this file from apk

Comment: please create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

The file is corrupted. If you do not have a backup somewhere else or if it is not in a version control system, then you can try to restore it using Android Studio.

In Android Studio right-click on the file -> Local History -> Show History

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/viewing-local-history-of-a-file-or-folder.html

Comment: I checked your suggestion,I watched Local History->Show History , but History is empty ((((

Answer (score 0):

This is a worst case idea, if you have latest debug APK,  de-Compile it and get appropriate file.

Comment: I tried to decomile APK file , but I couldn't get this class

Comment: If not, you have to write it from scratch. Happy coding :)